# Has anybody created a Joint Plot (Density in middle/Distributions across the axis) in Power BI without Python/R? How?

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerquery, deneb

I need to create any variation of the depicted plots below with two variables/fields in Power BI.

Moreover, I need to be able to publish these plots to Power BI Service and subsequently embed them in a SharePoint Site Page. I believe this **disallows the use of any programming language** to generate the plots. Please provide guidance in generating said plots in Power BI natively. Should I maybe try to generate each component (Density and Frequency Distributions) individually then adjust their positions?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create these using Deneb and Vega or Vega-Lite.

Deneb: https://deneb-viz.github.io/

VL: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/

A video showing you exactly how to create the viz in Power BI: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FlzlSozY3VE&t=34s

[image]

Comment: I left out one thing in my post, but that is that using these third party visuals hinges on me being granted access to MS AppSource by our IT department. That said, I will put in a request (something I should've done earlier) and we'll have to see how it goes.